# Transforming csv to xml in dataweaver

Tags: xml, csv, mule, dataweave

I am trying to transform a csv file to xml.
I have successfully configured my dataweaver component.
But when I test with my files, I see null values getting populated to xml file.
Do you know what is the reason or where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more specifics?

Comment: Your input example? script? expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv file I was trying to process does not have any header and data are not in quotes("").
The default property for csv in data weaver is, it assumes data fields are quoted and header is present.
So I made following changes and it has worked perfectly

```
 <dw:reader-property name="quote" value=" "/>
 <dw:reader-property name="header" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell dataweave to not output null values:
`%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"`

From the documentation:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#skip-on-null